# unique and replace in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have huge dataset with more than 100 columns that contain non-null values that I want to replace (and leave all the null values as is). Some columns, however, should stay untouched. 
I am planning to do the following:
1) find unique values in these columns 
2) replace this values with 1

Problem:
1) something like this barely possible to use for 100+ columns:

```
np.unique(df[['Col1', 'Col2']].values)
```

2) how do I apply than loc to all these columns? code below  does not work

```
df_2.loc[df_2[['col1','col2','col3']] !=0, ['col1','col2','col3']] = 1
```

Maybe there is more reasonable and elegant way to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not very clear on what you're trying to achieve. You just want to replace non-null values with 1, but only in certain columns?

Comment: yes, exactly. also it would be nice to do that using index of columns for example. there are a lot of columns. to list each one is a bit problematic. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
c = ['col1','col2','col3']
df_2[c] = df_2[c].mask(df_2[c] != 0, 1)
```

Or compare by not equal with [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and cast mask by integers with [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'col1':[0,5,0,5,5,0],
         'col2':[7,8,9,0,2,0],
         'col3':[0,0,5,7,0,0],
         'E':[5,0,6,9,2,0],
})

c = ['col1','col2','col3']
df_2[c] = df_2[c].ne(0).astype(int)
print (df_2)
   A  col1  col2  col3  E
0  a     0     1     0  5
1  b     1     1     0  0
2  c     0     1     1  6
3  d     1     0     1  9
4  e     1     1     0  2
5  f     0     0     0  0
```

EDIT: For select columns by positions use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
idx = np.r_[6:71,82]
df_2.iloc[:, idx] = df_2.iloc[:, idx].ne(0).astype(int)
```

Or first solution:

```
df_2.iloc[:, idx] = df_2.iloc[:, idx].mask(df_2.iloc[:, idx]] != 0, 1)
```

Comment: thanks. there are a lot of columns. any faster way to define the c through indexes for example? thanks

Comment: @MayyaLihovodov - Can you be more specific? E.g. from 10 to 90 columns?

Comment: there are 66 columns that require replacement I mentioned

Comment: @MayyaLihovodov - How columns should be distinguish?

Comment: I indexed each one. basically these are: df.iloc[:, np.r_[6:71,82]]

Comment: @MayyaLihovodov - Answer was edited for working with `iloc`

Comment: @MayyaLihovodov - It seems you forget for `[c]` in  `df_2[c] = ` for assign only to filtered columns

Comment: this is great but columns that should not be changed are gone))))

Comment: @MayyaLihovodov - so filtering is also in left side, before `=` ?